# EF 5.0 Code First Quit Creating Database

Tags: entity-framework-5

I had everything working fine with automatic migrations set up and working.  I had just made a number of foreign key changes in my domain classes and when I started my app I got an illegal column "CreatedOn" exception.  Browsing I found that this error is typically due to moving from ef 4 to ef 5 and back.  I've always just used ef 5.  I couldn't find any reason for the error so I decided to go back to basics.  I turned off migrations and set my initializer to "DropAndCraeteAlways".  It dropped the db but didn't create a new one.  So I moved further back to basics and removed migrations altogether and set the initilizer to "CreateIfNoneExists".  Still no db creation.  I'm at a loss as to what else to try or how to debug.  The only exception I'm getting is when I try to initialize the db I get a db not found which is obvious.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More data.  I'm finding that when using "DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges" EF first drops the db and then when it finds model changes it attempts to create a new db.  However, if it has a problem creating the db for do to some coding error the db is not created.  This leaves EF in some limbo state that's not allowing it to create a db even after model changes that may have caused the creation problem have been removed.

Comment: More - Is there anyway to reset EF to think nothing has been created so that it can start over creating a new db?  Going back to the default "CreateDatabaseIfNoneExists" doesn't work in this limbo state.

Comment: I've the same kind of problem. I used code first many times before and now, with that new project, EF won't create the tables no matter what I try. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework can get a bit grumpy if it cannot figure out how to resolve relationships - do you have any more details of the error? Bear in mind the final error you see may be the result of a failure earlier in the chain.

You might be able to see more by running the Update-Database command in the package manager console.

Might be worth looking at the [Fluent Relationship API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx), it's written for 4.1 but I believe it is much the same.